# MetaWear (Mbientlab) Android Activity detection on Bmi270

Tags: java, android

The [swift api](https://mbientlab.com/iosdocs/latest/accelerometer.html#activity-detector) supports the activity detector on the BMI270. I'm trying to use that same feature with the Android SDK.

I forked the MetaWear Android SDK to add the feature: https://gist.github.com/tran-simon/bf66dc4ce9724b11d3f2a5109cd3a31b

`createMessage` never gets called. I tried to set every registers just like in the C++ code, but it still does not work?

Is there anything I forgot to setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to implement the activity detection. I opened a pull request: https://github.com/mbientlab/MetaWear-SDK-Android/pull/30